# Refresh property every hour in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb, property-placeholder

Using this code

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="file:${basedir}/etc/foo.properties"/>
```

Camel load foo.properties at application start: is there a way to reload foo.properties every hour?

It can be useful if foo.properties changes.

Answer (score 2):

The camel-properties component has a property that can be used to control if properties have to be cached or not, see: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/properties-component.adoc